# How to make a fluid div with a custom shape

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, responsive-design

I have a div that will be the header of the site I'm working on that is a custom shape. The issue I am having is that the header needs to resize horizontally while retaining the integrity of the border radius and curves that are part of the shape. The problem with just using a transparent div with the shape as a background SVG is that when the window is resized, the integrity of the border radius and the angled section of the graphic are lost, meaning they get distorted into another shape. Here is an image of the shape:
[image: Custom div shape]

The initial way I attempted to create this element was by placing it as an SVG, and resizing one of the line segments of the SVG in Javascript, but the performance on this was very poor, it was overly-complicated, and it was difficult to get the sizing correct.

The closest I got to the desired result was by cutting the right side tail of the SVG and using it as an :after element, which gave me the horizontal fluidity I was looking for, but encountered issues with matching the border color of the div and the stroke of the SVG. The div uses a translucent white background and a translucent colored border. Since the border is technically "on top" of the white background, the resulting color value is dynamic depending on the background of the page. This makes it difficult to match the stroke of the SVG and the border color of the div. There was also an issue where a vertical line would show up at different resolutions between the div and :after SVG element. You can see in the picture below that this method is not ideal, the SVG border color and width does not match the div on the left, and if you look closely there is a gap between the two elements (much more visible on a dark background which the site will be using).

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  margin: 10px 20px;
}

.header {
  background-color: rgb(217 217 217 / 0.5);
  border: 3px solid rgb(122 112 158 / 0.5);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 24px;
  border-right: none;
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% - 305px);
  height: 60px;
  position: relative;
}

.header:after {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='308' height='65' viewBox='0 0 308 65' fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='M0.00179921 3.00586H293.755C296.737 3.00586 299.597 4.08424 301.706 6.00378C303.815 7.92331 305 10.5268 305 13.2414V22.7809C305 25.4955 303.815 28.099 301.706 30.0185C299.597 31.938 296.737 33.0164 293.755 33.0164H126.396C75.9048 33.0164 52.8027 61.9625 0 61.9625L0.00179921 3.00586Z' fill='%23D9D9D9' fill-opacity='0.5'/%3E%3Cpath d='M293.755 0.00585938C297.447 0.00585938 301.037 1.33813 303.726 3.78519C306.424 6.24078 308 9.6351 308 13.2414V22.7809C308 26.3872 306.424 29.7815 303.726 32.2371C301.037 34.6842 297.447 36.0164 293.755 36.0164H126.396C101.996 36.0164 84.1741 42.9185 65.6587 50.0893L65.1482 50.287C46.4357 57.5333 27.0057 64.9625 9.15527e-05 64.9625V61.9625C1.01084 61.9625 2.01071 61.9519 3.00009 61.9311C28.1433 61.4023 46.5167 54.2861 64.6923 47.2465C83.1648 40.0919 101.433 33.0164 126.396 33.0164H293.755C296.737 33.0164 299.597 31.938 301.706 30.0185C303.815 28.099 305 25.4955 305 22.7809V13.2414C305 10.5268 303.815 7.92331 301.706 6.00378C299.597 4.08424 296.737 3.00586 293.755 3.00586H0.00189066L0 0.00585938H293.755Z' fill='rgb(122 112 158 / .50)' /%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A");
  content: "";
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 310px;
  height: 66px;
  left: 100%;
  top: -3px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track with splitting up the image. You could either split the png you provided in your example, or if you have access to the tools, you could make three svgs.

Using the png you provided as an example, I made a new image 50px wide starting from the left. I made a second image 500px wide starting from the right. Finally, for the center, I made a third image that was only 1px wide taken from the horizontal center of the provided png. That 1px can be repeated horizontally to give the illusion that it is one image.

There are many ways to assemble them for the header. You could use a table, a grid, divs with positioning and float. I chose to use flex.

```
body {
  background-color: black;
  margin: 10px 20px;
}
.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  height: 96px;
}
.header_left {
  flex-grow: 0;
  background-image: url("h_left.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 50px;
  max-width: 50px;
  min-width: 50px;
}

.header_middle {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: block;
  background-image: url("h_mid.png");
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

.header_right {
  flex-grow: 0;
  display: block;
  background-image: url("h_right.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 500px;
  max-width: 500px;
  min-width: 500px;
}
```

```
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <div class="header_left"></div>
            <div class="header_middle"></div>
            <div class="header_right"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
```